# The Lévy-Khinchine and the Kolmogorov canonical representation

Tags: characteristic-functions, levy-processes

I am currently reading a book by Lukacs on characteristic functions.

He states that the Kolmogorov canonical representation, given by

$$\log \phi(\omega)=i\omega c+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\exp(i\omega x)-1-{i\omega x}\Big)\frac{dK(x)}{x^2}$$

where

$$K(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x(1+y^2)\;dF(y)$$

and

$$c = a +\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\;dF(y)$$

can be deduced from the Lévy-Khinchine canonical representation given by

$$\log \phi(\omega)=i\omega a+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\exp(i\omega x)-1-\frac{i\omega x}{1+x^2}\Big)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\;dF(x)$$

I cannot seem to wrap my head around this one. Can anyone clear up what is happening here? Preferebely in a step-by-step manner.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no typo in the definition of $c$? As far as I can see it should read $$c = a + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \, d\color{red}{K}(y).$$